# How to pass closure as constructor parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm working with 3rd party library and trying to register my own control, unfortunally it requires me to pass constructor as parameter, which was not problem before, but now I'm trying to add another dependency to the control and don't know how to pass the closure as parameter to satisfy the parameter type.

The registration method has following signature:

```
class Registrator {
    static Add(controlName: string, component: new (...params: any[]) => Control): void;
}
```

I had to followin code before, but after refactoring I exported some code and made my control dependant on it:

```
//Old code - working
Registrator.Add("CountdownTimer", Controls.CountdownTimer);
//Trying to add Dependency - can't compile
const countdownTimerFormater = new Objects.Time.TimeFormater();
Registrator.Add("CountdownTimer", (...params: any[]) => return new Controls.CountdownTimer(<HTMLElement>(params[0]), countdownTimerFormater));
```

Compiler error is:
Argument of type '(...params: any[])=>CountdownTimer' is not assagnable to parameter of type 'new (params: any[])=>Control'.
Type '(...params: any[])=> CountdownTimer' provides no match for signature 'new (...params:any[]): Control'.

Params are dependant on the context of the control, in my case it will always have length of 1 and pass `HTMLElement` which should server as parent for the control.
Considering that everything is function in javascript I feel like there should be a way to pass closure that satisfy the parameter or someway to push my dependency to the params from my code.

Comment: Did you tried to change `component: new (...params: any[]) => Control` to `component:
 (...params: any[]) => Control`

Comment: @cyrix Can't change the signature of Registrator.Add since it is not my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without violating dependency injection and declaring entire class in application entry point, or extending with anonymous class I changed the order of arguments and went with bind function.

```
Registrator.Add("CountdownTimer", Controls.CountdownTimer.bind(null, new Objects.Time.TimeFormater()));
```

Another way that is possible to use and without changing the order of arguments, but seemed ugly is extending the base class with anonymous class, which is very similar to gilamran's answer, just without declaring entire class in application entry point:

```
Registrator.Add("CountdownTimer", class extends CountdownTimer {
    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        super(element, new Objects.Time.TimeFormater());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The requested parameter only asks for something that when it will do `new` on it, it will return a `Control` class.

Do it like this (Assuming `CountdownTimer` is of type `Control`):

```
Registrator.Add("CountdownTimer", Controls.CountdownTimer);
```

If you want to create the countdownTimerFormater on the CountdownTime, you can define the class inline, like this:

```
Registrator.Add("CountdownTimer", class CountdownTimer {
    private countdownTimerFormater; 

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.countdownTimerFormater = new Objects.Time.TimeFormater();
    }
 }
);
```

Comment: I had it like that, but changed my control afterwards and it now requires another dependency/parameter, is there a way to write it such that I can pass the dependency there?

Comment: [Answer edited] It looks like the code which does the `new` will pass only specific parameters to the constructor. If you want access to other classes, you'll need a different way to get them, like inline class declaration.